# How to display data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I created an Online Time Table and it's working fine and user or me can add new time-table row by using some data and my end result is like.

This is my SQL query (Please don't warn me to use MySQLi or PDO, I know about them, but this is a private application and I can write unsafe codes thought.)

```
 $date = date("d/m/y");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `s_timetable` WHERE `date` = '$date'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

     while ($fetch_data = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$fetch_data['batch_info']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$fetch_data['class_info']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$fetch_data['subject_info']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$fetch_data['teacher_info'].  "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
     }
   ?>
```

but after querying this to database, I got lots of results with same value, how can i show them as group.
Example:
 `LDC batch` - `08:09` - `science` - `Ashok B.`
`LDC batch` - `09-10` - `English` - `Jaky`
`LDC batch` - `10-11` - `Maths` - `Bella`

Now how i can display these data as table, with title of `LDC batch` as that repeat in all and then `time` `subject` and `teacher` info with table body.

Comment: @HimanshuPatel Yaa but there will be several different batches, for example if there is 10 different batch with 5-10 row in each about class, subject, teacher. SO in this example there will be total 50 rows and in all batch name will be repeated, i just want to show batch name as title or head of table and results specific to that row under table body, but problem is how could i do that.

Comment: learn about mysql group by and you will get the values already grouped

Comment: @LelioFaieta I tried this query earlier but I don't know how to display that value.
`SELECT * FROM `s_timetable` WHERE `date` = '$date' GROUP BY `batch_info`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option here is to present a 3 column HTML table containing the time, subject, and teacher data for each batch.  When the batch type changes in the result set, a new row can be printed as a header.

```
$header = "";
while ($fetch_data = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    if ($header = "" || $header != $fetch_data['batch_info']) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">".$fetch_data['batch_info']."</td></tr>";
        $header = $fetch_data['batch_info'];
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$fetch_data['class_info']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$fetch_data['subject_info']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$fetch_data['teacher_info'].  "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
```

**Update:**

As @apokryfos pointed out, you should order your result set by the `batch_info` column to ensure that records belonging to the same batch are always adjacent.  So your query might become:

```
SELECT *
FROM s_timetable
WHERE date = '$date'
ORDER BY batch_info
```

Comment: I'd also `order by batch_info` to be on the safe side

Comment: @apokryfos I already tried that but it looks like not working in this problem, can you share codes of your approach.

Comment: @Jaky what do you mean as "non working"? it's just a `order by batch_info` at the end of your query

Comment: @LelioFaieta I mean when i added `order by batch_info` i just got 2-2 rows in each instead of all rows in single batch.

Comment: @apokryfos Why I'm only getting 2-2 rows instead of all (in some batch around 8-10) rows in a single batch table.

Comment: @Jaky when you run the query in the command line does it show all the rows you need?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes it works there in PHP My Admin's SQL terminal.